# Convert Model variable to a Context variable in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is what I already have :

```java
model.addAttribute("var1", var1);
model.addAttribute("var99", var99);
```

This is what I have to do - so its a complete re-do :

```java
Context ctx = new Context();

ctx.setVariable("var1", var1);
ctx.setVariable("var99", var99);
```

Is there a way to set `model` to `ctx` ?

What I really want to do :

```java
String htmlTemplate = myTemplateEngine.process("html/foo.html", ctx);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Model` class actually has `asMap()` method. You can check in [java docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html#asMap()) . `Context` class in turn has `context.setVariables()` method. You can check it [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/context/AbstractContext.html#setVariables(java.util.Map)). It means you can write something like this:

```java
ctx.setVariables(model.asMap());
```

It is also worth noting that you should use the `Model` class and the `Context` class as they have different responsibilities. Since `Model` class is used to add attributes to a model that will be used to render a view, and the `Context` class is used to add attributes to a context that will be used to process a Thymeleaf template.

Comment: Thanks for the solution - I just wanted to test something quickly and not change the model variable.